# How to add custom snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have defined a custom snippet as below into `javascriptreact.json`

```
{
    "Console Logging": {
      "prefix": "clg",
      "body": "console.log('DEBUG::${1:key}', ${1:key});",
      "description": "Console Logging with DEBUG key"
    }
}
```

Now I thought in any files with extension `.js`, I can simply type `clg` and the above `body` will showed up but that's not the case. It seems like I still need to find some way to sort of "activate" the snippet? Unlike atom where it gets activated automatically? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javascriptreact.json` is apparently for `.jsx` files only.   So you could make `.jsx` specific snippets if you wanted to that would not work in `.js` files.  Maybe there are some people who would like that.

It could be solved by putting the snippet into a global snippet file (perhaps with the scope limitations if you find that necessary).

Or you could simply put your snippet into `javascript.json` snippets file.

Finally if you **really** want to put your react snippets into `javascriptreact.json` and have them available in both `.js` and `.jsx` files try this setting:

```
"files.associations": {"*.js": "javascriptreact"},
```

but then `javascript.json` snippets won't work in `.js` files!  So you probably don't want that.  Just use the `javascript.json` snippets file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is for some reason the snippet can't be recognized if it's inside `javascriptreact.json` but if I added it into another custom file `CustomJavascript.code-snippets`, and add a `scope` property for each of the snippets as below:

```
"Console Logging": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "clg",
    "body": "console.log('DEBUG::${1:key}', ${1:key});",
    "description": "Console Logging with DEBUG key"
},
```